# Output of a command to the first line of a file

Tags: linux, files, command

I am trying to insert output of a command into the first line of a file.

For example, I have a file named "list.txt" and want to insert a text containing all the file names in that folder. A way to direct the output of `ls` command to the first line of list.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people know of sed as a tool for search and regex-based search and replece, but it is a full editor capable of making edits.

So You could issue a command like this.  Which would insert (`1 i`) the first line of the ls command `$(ls| head -1)` into the `list.txt` file **inplace** (`-i`).

```
sed -i "1 i$(ls| head -1)" list.txt
```

Comment: Dear @Zoredache. Thank you for your answer. This is really an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native way to redirect to the first line of a file, but you could use a temporary file to achieve this anyway. For example, first append the output to `list2.txt`, then cat `list.txt` into it and write the entire output back to `list.txt`:

```
ls > list2.txt
cat list.txt >> list2.txt
mv list2.txt list.txt
```

That way you should end up with what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Zoredache's answer seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Hamdi You're welcome and you are right. That seems like a more elegant solution for the matter.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this but you could just use multiple files. For example:

```
ls | head -n 1 > temp-list.txt
cat list.txt >> temp-list.txt
mv temp-list.txt list.txt
```

Comment: Oldskool you beat me by 6 seconds =)

Comment: @Hamdi note that my ls command gets piped into "head -n 1" so it's only the first line that gets inserted, if you want to include everything that's returned by the first command then skip piping it through head.

Comment: Thank you @Martin for your time. Zoredache's answer seems more appropriate.